# Label and pins not showing using Xamarin.Forms.Map

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maps

VS 2019 with all updates.
I install Xamarin.Forms.Map using nuget.

Using Xamarin Android to display a map with a pin point.

Front end XAML is

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <maps:Map x:Name="Map"/>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

In code-behind i have

```
    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(10)));

        var pin = new Pin()
        {
            Position = new Position(37, -122),
            Label = "Some Pin!"
        };
        map.Pins.Add(pin);

        var cp = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = map,
        };
    }
```

Which i have followed from MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.maps.map?view=xamarin-forms.

I then click pixel_2_pie_api_28 (F5) and once the page loads it shows a map but not to the location i set (i randomly changed the position values) or the pin point or even label? What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have quite a few problems in your code

```
   // you already have a map declared in your XAML, you do not need to do it again
   var map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(10)));

    var pin = new Pin()
    {
        Position = new Position(37, -122),
        Label = "Some Pin!"
    };

    // add this to your existing XAML map, which you named "Map"
    Map.Pins.Add(pin);

    // you already have a ContentPage, you don't need to declare a new one
    var cp = new ContentPage
    {
        Content = map,
    };
```

all you need to do

```
    var pin = new Pin()
    {
        Position = new Position(37, -122),
        Label = "Some Pin!"
    };

    Map.Pins.Add(pin);
```

to move the map to a specific position

```
var span = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(10));
Map.MoveToRegion(span);
```

Comment: Thanks - I added just last bit of code and that has the exact same problem? I dont see the label. The map shows (always defaults to Rome where i do not reside)?

Comment: the default location for the simulator is Rome.  If you want to move the map, see my edit

Comment: The label displays when you click on a Pin.  It is not displayed always as default.